# Can't post to facebook wall because of authentication problems?

Tags: php, facebook

I can't get the following code to post to the wall of user with user id 514559322.  However, if I replace the value of $uid with the string 'me', I am able to post to my own wall.

```
<?php
require_once "../src/facebook.php";

$app_id = "my app id";
$app_secret = "my app secret";
$uid = 514559322;

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

// Get the url to redirect for login to facebook
// and request permission to write on the user's wall.
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array('scope' => 'publish_stream')
);

// If not authenticated, redirect to the facebook login dialog.
// The $login_url will take care of redirecting back to us
// after successful login.
if (! $facebook->getUser()) {
    echo <<< EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "$login_url";
</script>;
EOT;

    exit;
}

// Do the wall post.
$facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post", array(
    message => "Hello win95",
    picture => "http://cdn.papyimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Windows-95-500x312.png",
    link => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95",
    name => "Go windows 95",
    caption => "Caption - this is the best operating system in the world!"
));
?>
```

How do I allow my php script to post the wall of user with uid 514559322?

After adding a try catch loop around the api call, here's the Exception message I got:

```
OAuthException: (#1) An error occured while creating the share
```

So where in my code do i supply authentication information?  Or appropriate  auth tokens?

Comment: Add `try { [POST TO WALL CODE] } catch (FacebookApiException $e) { exit($e); }` to see the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `access_token` param:

```
// Do the wall post.
$facebook->api("/$uid/feed", 'post', array(
    'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
    'message' => "Hello win95",
    'picture' => "http://cdn.papyimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Windows-95-500x312.png",
    'link' => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95",
    'name' => "Go windows 95",
    'caption' => "Caption - this is the best operating system in the world!"
));
```

Or, you need the `offline_access` permission, which is not good, because will be deprecated soon..

Answer (score 1):

Your user needs to auth your app for "offline_access,publish_stream" (although this is now being replaced, see here http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

You can then inject the token in the api call

```
$res = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post);
```

where $post is a array of $access_token and $message